# How to read and open two different files in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have observed in this code that we can't open the file after we have readFile.

The computer complains about `Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end`

Of course if I remove the `readFile` function then this error goes away but I want to understand why this error is occurring even though I am using two different files for reading and opening.

What is the way to read and open two different files?

```js
var objHttp = require('http');
var objFS = require('fs');

objHttp.createServer(function(argClientRequest, argResult) {
    objFS.readFile('z.html',
        function(argError, argData) {
            argResult.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            });
            argResult.write(argData);
            argResult.end();
        }
    );
    objFS.open('mynewfile1.txt', 'r', (argErr, argFD) => {
        if (argErr) throw argErr;

        objFS.readFile('mynewfile1.txt',
            function(argError, argData) {
                if (argError) throw argError;

                argResult.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                });
                argResult.write(argData);
                return argResult.end();
            }
        );


        objFS.close(argFD, (argErr) => {
            if (argErr) throw argErr;

        });
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var objHttp = require('http');
var objFS = require('fs');
function firstReader(argResult){

    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        objFS.readFile("z.html",
        function(argError, argData) {
            argResult.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            });
            argResult.write(argData);
         
        }
    );
    })
   
}
function secondReader(argResult){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        objFS.open('mynewfile1.txt', 'r', (argErr, argFD) => {
            if (argErr) throw argErr;
    
            objFS.readFile('mynewfile1.txt',
                function(argError, argData) {
                    if (argError) reject();
    
                    argResult.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                    });
                    argResult.write(argData);
                }
            );
    
    
            objFS.close(argFD, (argErr) => {
                if (argErr) reject();
    
            });
        });
    })
}
objHttp.createServer(function(argClientRequest, argResult) {
   Promise.all([firstReader(argResult),secondReader(argResult)]).then(function(){
    argResult.end();
   }).catch(function(){
    argResult.end();
   })
   
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `argResult.end();` This gets returned immediately after reading `z.html` and when `mynewfile1.txt` is read, the headers and already sent to the client. You are trying to send it again which is technically not possible. You will have to send the responses only once.

Answer (score 1):

`argResult` is a stream. In the first `objFS.readFile` call you are ending the `argResult` stream and then again you are trying to write to the `argResult` stream in the second `objFS.readFile` call. That is why you are getting the error.

The problem is not with file access. If you remove the http listener and run the code then you will see no error in the console.

Answer (score 1):

you are using argResult.end(); twice. You cannot send response twice.
For this problem you need to use promise the read the file and resolve them after callback. You can use

```
Promise.All([promise1,promise2]).then((data)=>{
argResult.end();
})
```

here promise1 is first file reader and promise2 is second file reader

and then send the response back when both the promise are resolved